# Are macros always evaluated prior to expressions with Jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

What is the order of operations when rendering a template with statements like `macro` or `do`? It seems like statements are handled prior to expressions regardless of their order in the template:

In the example below, I would have expected `Heres the list before macro call: {{ things }}` to be "rendered" first, prior to the macro being called.

```
import jinja2

t = """Start of template
{% set things = [] %}
{{ things }}

{% macro mymacro(item) %}
{% do things.append(item) %}
Adding {{ item }} to the list
{% endmacro %}

Heres the list before macro call: {{ things }}
{{ mymacro('1') }}
Heres the list after macro call: {{ things }}
"""

e = jinja2.Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.do'])
template = e.from_string(t)
print(template.render())
```

Resulting output:

```
Start of template

[]



Heres the list before macro call: ['1']


Adding 1 to the list

Heres the list after macro call: ['1']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this on the Github issues: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/148#issuecomment-10267923

The important part to me is that the template is rendered by generating intermediate python code, then evaluating that code. In the end, the code used to make the template looks similar to this:

```
u'\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' % (
        l_my_list,
        context.call(l_add_list, l_my_list),
        context.call(l_add_list, l_my_list),
        context.call(l_add_list, l_my_list),
    )
```

This can be modeled with the following code:

```
def a( l ):
    l.append( 4 )
    return l
l = list()
print '%s %s %s' % ( a( l ), a( l ), a( l ) )
# Output: [4, 4, 4] [4, 4, 4] [4, 4, 4]
```

Essentially each function is returning a reference to a the same list, not a new copy of the list. So the results are not what you might expect. This was an old issue that didn't receive much interest, so I don't think there are any plans to change how it works.